# react-admin ListGuesser showing "No results found"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-admin

```
My Resource -:
<Resource name="ReliabilityEventLog" list={ListGuesser} />


This is my response from the server_:

{
"data": {
"items": [{
"createdAt": "2020-12-04T04:24:00.118Z",
"deletedAt": null,
"eventName": "Confirmed Withdraw* between 5 and 24 hrs",
"eventDate": "2020-12-04T00:00:00.000Z",
"eventPoint": -20,
"shiftId": 44332,
"facilityName": "Tester Facility Friendswood",
"facilityId": 927,
"id": 4,
"nurseId": 12508,
]}}
```

The ListGuesser renders "no results found" and the data was returned from the network tab.

Is there any explanation for this behavior or how to fix it? Any help will be appraciated.

Comment: Please specify your question.

Comment: I'm trying to display a list using the ListGuesser, The list guesser renders "No result found" whereas, The backend sent back a data response. Do you have an idea what the problem is?

Comment: Could you post your `dataProvider` ? It could be the way you pass the response through the react-admin state.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Problem is from my graphQL server not returning the count of the query, so the dataProvider was unable to paginate the result successfully, which leads to an inability to render.

Answer (score 2):

Your `dataProvider.getList()` should return an object containing an array of records in the 'data' key:

```
{
"data": [{
     "createdAt": "2020-12-04T04:24:00.118Z",
     "deletedAt": null,
     "eventName": "Confirmed Withdraw* between 5 and 24 hrs",
     "eventDate": "2020-12-04T00:00:00.000Z",
     "eventPoint": -20,
     "shiftId": 44332,
     "facilityName": "Tester Facility Friendswood",
     "facilityId": 927,
     "id": 4,
     "nurseId": 12508,
   }]
}
```

See the official react-admin documentation about dataProvider response format for details:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#response-format